# Multiple subscriptions on same Instagram realtime update

Tags: real-time, instagram

I have implemented handling subscription notifications for user media updates and it works really great. However, I cannot find a way having two subscriptions of the same type at the same time, e.g. user media updates.

Setting up a subscription is straight forward:

```
curl -F 'client_id=CLIENT-ID' \
     -F 'client_secret=CLIENT-SECRET' \
     -F 'object=user' \
     -F 'aspect=media' \
     -F 'verify_token=myVerifyToken' \
     -F 'callback_url=http://YOUR-CALLBACK/URL' \
     https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions
```

I would like to find a solution that can publish subscription notifications to both production environment AND test environment as well. But calling the above in sequence, with one for production and one for test will only keep the last subscription.

```
Production: www.myservice.com/instagramcallback
Test: www.test.myservice.com/instagramcallback
```

Instagram real-time photo updates: https://instagram.com/developer/realtime/

> EDIT

Instagram does not publish to more than one subscription.

Comment: I don't think Instagram would post the same data to two different servers. I'm afraid you need to register two different client apps and get independent updates. As an alternative, you might have your production environment "forward" the callback to your test environment and then they can independently get the data from Instagram.

Comment: You are correct! I forgot to post the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I think it goes even further than this... I get data for some users and not others.  My hunch is they only post the data to ONE app the user is subscribed too.  So if the user has already connected an app which subscribes to notifications, you won't receive them for your app.  Makes it useless.